# Redirect based on a specific query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What I want to achive is to redirect my page if there is a given query string.

For example, I want to redirect

```
http://example.com/?taguid=CSTAGUID3fffd76e5e7db1369860ad8e0e5ed3fa
```

to

```
http://example.com/map/?taguid=CSTAGUID3fffd76e5e7db1369860ad8e0e5ed3fa
```

So I want to pass this `taguid` param, but in the `map` directory.

I've tried with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)taguid= [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /map/\?taguid=$1 [L,R=301]
```

There are two problems.

- It does not pass the value of the taguid.
- It will goes to a redirect loop.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule from `DocumentRoot` .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)taguid= [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?$ /map/ [L,R=301]
```

`QUERY_STRING` is automatically carried over to target URL and there is no need to capture and pass the same query string.